# wait for already finished jobs

Tags: cluster-computing, hpc, pbs, qsub, torque

I launch a pbs script once others are completed. For that I use this commands:

```
$ job1=$(qsub job1.pbs)
$ jobN=$(qsub jobN.pbs)
$ qsub -W depend=afterok:$job1:$jobN join.pbs
```

This works, in most cases. However if I run the joining script when job1 and jobN are already finished, it will go idle indefinitely as it is waiting for the already-finished-jobs to finish. That sounds insane, but this is what happens. If I run `qstat` I can clearly see that my joining job is being held ('H')

```
$ qstat -u me
Job ID          Username Queue    Jobname    SessID NDS TSK Memory Time  S Time
--------------- -------- -------- ---------- ------ --- --- ------ ----- - -----
1990613            me    workq    join.pbs      --    1   1    --    --  H   --
```

However if at least one of the jobs is still running, while the other is already finished, then the joining script will not go idle and will finish.

So what are the solutions to deal with jobs that are already over? We clearly need this job to finish.

Comment: If the jobs are gone from `qstat`, that means you need to increase `keep_completed`. Otherwise, when the join job is ready to run, the dependency will never get satisfied, and the hold will never get released.

Comment: What version of Torque are you using? It could be you are experiencing a bug that is already fixed.

Answer (score 0):

When the join job starts, the server still needs to know about the depended-upon jobs; if either of those is gone from `qstat`, then you'll need to increase `keep_completed` in `qmgr`. Otherwise, when the join job is ready to run, the dependency will never get satisfied, and the hold will never get released.

To check: `$ qmgr -c 'print server keep_completed'`

To add/modify: `$ qmgr -c 'set server keep_completed=300'`

(I also believe you can set `keep_completed` on queues.)